# Page style changing on code generated by PHP when compared to static HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I'm currently working on a product page with dynamically fitting divs for the products. Those work perfectly when testing straight with HTML code, but when the exact same code comes from the PHP script the CSS styling slightly changes, completly breacking the justify of the elements and packing them all togheter. The site is still under construction but the difference can be seen here:

- Static HTML elements, working properly: http://200.145.153.175/marcotoledo/anual/produtos/copy.php

  - Page using PHP: http://200.145.153.175/marcotoledo/anual/produtos/index.php

Comment: Then its not exactly the same. _Simples_

Comment: Man you can read the page's source code, it's exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry, but it cant be.

Comment: A cursory check of the source code of the two pages proves them to be different. It really is as simple as that!

Comment: There are differences in whitespace in the source of the two pages which could possibly cause changes with spacing between elements.

Comment: That appears to be the most part that is not the same in addition to the large html comment: https://www.diffchecker.com/BbO84aQr

Comment: Are you sure they're identical?  https://www.diffchecker.com/PDSe1RQ1

Comment: Your PHP rendered HTML is missing whitespace text nodes which is necessary for text alignment.

Comment: how is this a php question? I see no source code here. If that php's inside one of those URL's you want us to visit, then that won't do any good later on, should that no longer exist. (Source) code needs to be part of the question.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I really wasn't thinking that the whitespaces would change all that much but I'm gonna try working on them and report back lol

Comment: It worked guys! Thank you so much, sorry if I sounded arrogant I just wasted more time than I'd like to admit with this stupid error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White space is important .... see : http://jsfiddle.net/nh82yz5t/

You need to adjust your php so that a new line or white space character is inserted between the closing and opening cont_produto `div` tags.

That is, you want

```
<div class="cont_produto">
    <!--Stuff -->
</div>
<div class="cont_produto">
    <!-- Stuff -->
</div>
```

**NOT**

```
<div class="cont_produto">
    <!--Stuff -->
</div><div class="cont_produto">
    <!-- Stuff -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML rendered by your PHP script is most likely adding the DOM elements without line breaks/whitespace which is causing the "text-align" on the parent container not to work.

**Here is an example using your sites CSS.**

```css
.produtos {
  text-align: justify;
  -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  -webkit-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) , 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.cont_produto {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    min-width: 120px;
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(187, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) , 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}
```

```html
<!-- With Line breaks -->

<div class="produtos">
  <div class="cont_produto">
    Some Image
  </div>
  <div class="cont_produto">
    Some Image
  </div>
  <div class="cont_produto">
    Some Image
  </div>
  <div class="cont_produto">
    Some Image
  </div>
</div>

<!-- No line breaks, most likely how your PHP is rendering -->

<div class="produtos"><div class="cont_produto">Some Image</div><div class="cont_produto">Some Image</div><div class="cont_produto">Some Image</div><div class="cont_produto">Some Image</div></div>
```